# iOS Base64 Lib that prevents CRLF

Tags: ios, base64, newline

I'm having troubles decoding/encoding a base64 string because of the CRLF on it.
I've tried this lib [**Base64.h**](http://www.koders.com/objectivec/fid5B401E9524F8DD92E9D88BE860B1683BB02CE1C1.aspx) and this one [**NSData+Base64.h**](http://colloquy.info/project/browser/trunk/NSDataAdditions.h?rev=1576) but both do not handle well the **CRLF**.

Anyone had this problem before?

Anyone has an advice on how to avoid these **CRLF**? I think [Android's Java lib](http://hi-android.info/src/android/util/Base64.java.html) is replacing this with a '0', am I correct?

```
public static final int CRLF = 4;
```

Comment: CRLF means two characters: CR:0x0d followed by LF:0x0a.

Comment: The decoded string length= 23, but should be 24, should I append those chars before continue?

Comment: WHy do you think the decoded string should be 24? Add the Base64 representation and the string to you question, that will help with answers.

Comment: Is 24 because the equivalent decode in Android decodes 24 bytes, or better a 24 length (unsiged char*) array.   This is the string: "+vqbiP7s3oe7/puJ8v2a3fOYnf3vmpap"

Comment: That string will need to generate a byte array with the following elements (signed, just an example) **{79 -16 74 79 54 -105 118 35 35 -32 11 94 30 -109 106 36 124 -98 6 53 2 -96 72 0}** (this is a private key that will match a public in a proprietary algorithm)

Answer (score 1):

Base64 encodes 64 characters, namely 'A-Za-z0-9+/' with a possible trailing '=' to indicate a non mod 3 length. CR+LF may be used as a line separator, generally decode each line separately.

See [Wikipedia Base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) for more information on CR+LF variants.

"+vqbiP7s3oe7/puJ8v2a3fOYnf3vmpap"
decoded is:
"FA FA 9B 88 FE EC DE 87 BB FE 9B 89 F2 FD 9A DD F3 98 9D FD EF 9A 96 A9"
The last character is not 0.